# Where pressed on bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am making an application where I want an object to move left, right and jump (up). Here is my code now:

```
package com.bjo.er;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;


public class Play extends View  {
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    Bitmap object;

    public Play(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        object = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brid);
   }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawBitmap(object, x, y, null);
        invalidate();
    } 
}
```

I want the user to be available press three different places on the screen to move the object. Some help would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a RelativeLayout for that. Make your Play view fill the screen and put 3 buttons above the Play view. Then you just have to register clickhandlers for those buttons and change the x and y values in there.

In order to use your custom Play view in a layout you need to add another constructor

```
public Play(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

You layout file could look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.bjo.er.Play
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively you can override onTouchEvent on your Play view.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
               //make use of event.getX() and event.getY()
            }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I`am already running the play class in another class so will I then rather import the xml file in an other file?

Answer (score 0):

Make your view implement onTouchListener,  ex: `textView.setOnTouchListener(this);`
The rest of the work will be in onTouch, for example:

```
float previousx,previousy;
int counter;

     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

     switch (event.getAction()) {


     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    float x =event.getX();
 float y =event.getY();   
 if(x==previousx && y==previousy)
Toast.makeText(this, "Touch a diffrent position",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else{
counter+=1;
if(counter==3) {
//move your object.Put code here
counter=0;
}
}    
previousx=x;
previousy=y;
 break;
     }
     return true;
     }
```